# White's test for heteroskedasticity in R

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, eviews, white-test

I am trying to estimate heteroskedasticity in R. I had Eviews available in my college's lab but not at home. I have been trying to use "het.test" package and `whites.htest` but the value that I get is different from what I get in Eviews. According to the author of the package, it is meant to do the same test as is done in Eviews.

My model looks like `A~B+C`. Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong.

I 1st run ols for equation `A~B+C`, after getting results, I clicked `View>Residual diagnostics>Heteroscadicity tests>White's (with Include white cross terms)` and then Press ok. The result i got was `Prob. F(5,27) = 0.2948`.

For R, i tried code at this link [this link][1], here is the edited code that i used.

```
library(vars) 
library(het.test)
dataset <- data.frame(A,B,C)) 
model1 <- VAR(dataset, p = 1) 
whites.htest(model1)
```

This gave me value of 0.63.

I tried searching this forum but none question seemed related. I am not a programmer not statistician so please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: It is going to be hard to say without more information. Can you paste in the code & output from the 3 tests? Can you say more about your data & your model? Etc.

Comment: @gung, please see as i have added details.

Comment: Why not `lm`? Why `VAR`?

Comment: @T C..Thank you for reply.. i must say, it was there in the code that i quoted, :( can you guide me to the correct usage?

Comment: Just write `lm(A ~ B + C, data = dataset)` where you have `VAR` right now.

Comment: Thank you, what does '= -' means? .. Ok sir let me check it...

Comment: Sir, i got this error: `Error in whites.htest(model1) : The VAR model must be of class varest.`

Comment: @T C, @gung, kindly guide why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `whites.htest()` function implements White's test for heteroskedasticity for vector autoregressions (VAR). It requires a `varest` object as input. However, from your description it seems that your model is not a VAR (vector autoregression) but a simple linear model.

Hence, the model should be estimated by `lm()` as previously suggested in the comments. Then you can use the `bptest()` function from the `lmtest` package to carry out White's test. The latter requires that you set up the terms in the auxiliary model yourself. It should look like this:

```
m <- lm(A ~ B + C, data = dataset)
bptest(m, ~ B*C + I(B^2) + I(C^2), data = dataset)
```

Note that `B*C` includes the main effects and their interaction (= product). Equivalently - and maybe somewhat more explicitly - we could also specify the auxiliary model as `~ A + B + I(A*B) + I(A^2) + I(B^2)`.

You can also look at

```
help("CigarettesB", package = "AER")
```

for a worked example.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I tried it and finally reached correct answer. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: @Faseeh, if this has resolved your question, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the check mark below the vote total on the left.

Comment: @gung, thank you for guiding me, i will keep visiting. :)

Comment: Sorry to reheat the thread, but what would be an example of a specification od White's test for three independent variables look like, i.e. A ~ B + C + D?

Comment: You need to include all regressors `B + C + D`, all squared regressors `I(B^2) + I(C^2) + I(D^2)`, and all pairwise interactions `B:C + B:D + C:D`. A somewhat shorter notation for this is `~ (B + C + D)^2 + I(B^2) + I(C^2) + I(D^2)`.