# White test for heteroscedasticity of simple linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, white-test

The question is straightforward: How to implement **White test** (a test for heteroscedasticity) for a simple linear regression model (lm object) in R?

I have tried "whites.htest(var.model)", however, it requires an input of *varest* object.

I learned that it requires to regress the squared of residuals with all squared variables, as well as their interaction terms. However, there seems no functions in R to implement this.

Can anyone give an example of it?

for example: if i have 4 variables in a regression equation lm(y~A+B+C+D). How should I write the white test code?

Note: my question is more general than this question that has been asked before: [White's test for heteroskedasticity in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155464/whites-test-for-heteroskedasticity-in-r)
It only explains how to implement when there are only two variables. However, what if I have more than 3 variables? How could I express the regression equation to implement White test?

Comment: Have you tried the function whites.htest()  in the package "het.test"?

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt as I have not tried the approach, but if the problem is only the inclusion of more than 2 parameters (as in the answer), try changing the formula objects, i.e., ``m <- lm(A ~ ., data = dataset)``, 
``bptest(m, ~ (.)^2, data = dataset)``. Here ``.`` represents _all_ variables from the dataset, but you can specify every one of them by hand. And ``(.)^2`` should work for the interaction part, since for the formula object ``(a+b)^2`` returns ``a^2 + b^2 + a:b`` where ``a:b`` denotes interaction. Again, this is purely technical, as I have not tried the approach